# YouTube always on top player

Tags: youtube

I want to work and watch videos at the same time. For downloaded videos I use `Media Player Classic's` (bundled with k-lite) compact view that plays on top of all apps.

Is there a YouTube Player (border less) that allows me to watch videos on top of all desktop applications?

Answer (score 5):

You can download the latest [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) (runs on Windows, MacOS, Linux) and then simply paste the YouTube link on VLC window. You can easily find the options to make the window borderless.

Comment: But I still don't know if suggesting desktop apps here is acceptable :)

Comment: Suggesting desktop apps where relevant is brilliant. The sites are different for categorization purposes only, not to prevent good answers from breaking the boundaries. An :upvote: to you, friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [Maxthon](http://www.maxthon.com) web browser. It has a feature for detaching flv videos from the main window. Also now Maxthon uses WebKit as the rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://www.labnol.org/software/watch-youtube-videos-while-multi-tasking/5791/) has a few suggestions. Youtube use to have a pop-out player, in which case you could just use a program like [Deskpins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html) to pin the window to be always-on-top.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the window youtube is playing in always on top using this AutoHotKey script fragment:

```
^1::Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

which basically says when Ctrl-1 is pressed make the active window always on top.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Actual Title Buttons (http://actualtools.com/titlebuttons/). It add new buttons (like always-on-top, transparent, roll up and some others) to the titlebar of all windows. 
Actual Window Manager (http://actualtools.com/windowmanager/) include this function, and also much more others..